# Making the file_names unique with timestamp in django image upoads

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-file-upload

**Intro:** I have a small piece of code that takes any image that is being added and makes it smaller and saves it. I am using a external library called [Filepond](https://github.com/pqina/filepond) for this.

**The Issue:**  If 2 users add same names to their images(different images). The second users image replaces the 1st users image and both users see the same image.

**What I want:** Add unique image names. My tries are below the present code. I need the best solution for this so the names are not too big but are unique

**Present Code:**

*fields.py:*

```
class FilePondField(forms.FileField):
widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'fileid'})

def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FilePondField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.name = name

def prepare_value(self, data):
    if not data:
        return None

    if isinstance(data, str):
        try:
            tu = TU.objects.get(upload_id=data)
        except TU.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return tu.upload_id

    name = data.name
    base = os.path.basename(name)
    file_id = "%s_%s" % (self.name, data.instance.pk)
    try:
        tu = TU.objects.get(file_id=file_id)
    except TU.DoesNotExist:
        upload_id = uuid()
        tu = TU(upload_id=upload_id, file_id=file_id,  # uuid(),
                upload_name=base, upload_type=TU.FILE_DATA)
        try:
            with data.storage.open(name, 'rb') as f:
                rd_data = File(f)
                tu.file.save(tu.file_id, rd_data, True)
            tu.save()
        except:
            pass

    return tu.upload_id

def clean(self, data, initial=None):
    self.initial = initial
    if not data:
        if self.required:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')
        return None
    return data

def save_cb(self, instance, modfld, tu):
    prename = os.path.join(modfld.upload_to, tu.upload_name)
    ffile = ImageFieldFile(instance, modfld, prename)

    try:
        with open(tu.get_file_path(), 'rb') as f:
            data = File(f)
            ffile.save(tu.upload_name, data, False)
    except:
        pass
    return ffile

def do_tmp(self, instance, modfld, value, cb):
    try:
        tu = TU.objects.get(upload_id=value)
        ffile = cb(instance, modfld, tu) if cb else None
    except TU.DoesNotExist:
        ffile = None
    else:
        tu.delete()

    file_id = "%s_%s" % (self.name, instance.pk)
    try:
        ogtu = TU.objects.get(file_id=file_id)
    except TU.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        ogtu.delete()

    return ffile

def save(self, instance, modfld, value):
    return self.do_tmp(instance, modfld, value, self.save_cb)

def del_tmp(self, instance, modfld, value):
    self.do_tmp(instance, modfld, value, None)

def bound_data(self, data, initial):
    return data

def has_changed(self, initial, data):
    if not initial:
        return data
    return initial != data
```

*forms.py*

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
img_fields = []

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for (fld, fargs) in self.img_fields:
        self.fields[fld] = FilePondField(fld, **fargs)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    commit = kwargs.get('commit', True)
    for (fld_nm, fargs) in self.img_fields:
        fld = dict([(f.name, f) for f in self._meta.model._meta.fields])[fld_nm]
        if isinstance(self.fields[fld_nm], FilePondField):
            self.fields[fld_nm] = self.fields[fld_nm].save(self.instance, fld, self.cleaned_data[fld_nm])

    return super(ImageForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def del_tmp (self):
    for (fld_nm, fargs) in self.img_fields:
        fld = dict([(f.name, f) for f in self._meta.model._meta.fields])[fld_nm]
        if isinstance(self.fields[fld_nm], FilePondField):
            self.fields[fld_nm].del_tmp(self.instance, fld, self.cleaned_data[fld_nm])
```

**My Approach:**

in *fields.py* I import

In the function `def prepare_value(self, data):` and `def do_tmp(self, instance, modfld, value, cb):` I make the below changes

```
...

file_id = "%s_%s_%s" % (self.name, data.instance.pk, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f"))
...
```

> Can someone comment on this or suggest a better alternative

Comment: when u upload any file, can u not name the file as `fileName_userName_timeStamp_RandomString`? this would help preventing overwrites by same as well as different user

Answer (score 1):

Just use `datetime.now()` value for the file name such as below:

```
from datetime import datetime
open(str(datetime.now()) + ".txt", "w+")
```

Result: It creates a file named `2019-04-22 00:21:31.862001.txt`

Comment: I am sorry I din't get it. I can name imagefiles as ".txt"

Comment: Name it as you want, I just want to show the solution, after up to you tu use .jpg or .png at this point

Comment: where I am replacing your code `with open(tu.get_file_path(), 'rb') as f:` here? or `with data.storage.open(name, 'rb') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

make the name a variable like this

```
name = "Your-General-Name-{}".format((int(time.time())))
```

and then put it in your loop so that the time.time() value changes each time. You obviously dont have to use `time.time()`. you could use `datetime.datetime.now()` etc. but then you'd just replace the time function.